# From .click to .delay jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In for an animation. And on the template it was using a `.click` jQuery, I tried to change it into a `.delay` so I would not need to click on the element so it would animate after a few seconds. But it wouldn't work. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Source (below)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Split Flap</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery/jquery.splitflap.js"></script>
<style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 20px;
      background: grey;
      color: white;
      font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
      font-size: 24px;
    }

    .example {
      padding: 0 0 10px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    h1 {
      margin: 0 0 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: normal;
      background: #333333;
    }

    .splitflap {
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="example">
    <h1>Simple Split-Flap</h1>

    <div class="do-splitflap">Hello World !</div>

    <div class="do-splitflap">Testing this sh?t</div>
    <div class="resized-splitflap">PHILIP</div>
    <div class="resized-splitflap">PINES?</div>
  </div>

  <div class="example">
    <h1>Autoplay disabled</h1>

    <div class="click-splitflap">It s nice</div>
  </div>

  <div class="example">
    <h1>JS-set text</h1>

    <div class="empty-splitflap"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="example">
    <h1>Modified size</h1>

    <div class="resized-splitflap">It s a Small World</div>
  </div>

  <script>
    (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.do-splitflap')
          .splitFlap();

        $('.click-splitflap')
          .splitFlap({
            textInit: 'Click me ',
            autoplay: false,
            onComplete: function() {
              console.log('Done !');
            }
          })
          .click(function() {
            $(this).splitFlap('splitflap').animate();
          });

        $('.empty-splitflap')
          .splitFlap({
            text: 'This is JS'
          });

        var ratio = 0.5;
        $('.resized-splitflap')
          .splitFlap({
            charWidth: 50 * ratio,
            charHeight: 100 * ratio,
            imageSize: (2500 * ratio) + 'px ' + (100 * ratio) + 'px'
          });
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>

  <a href="https://github.com/zemax/jquery-splitFlap"><img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;" src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/e7bbb0521b397edbd5fe43e7f760759336b5e05f/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f6769746875622f726962626f6e732f666f726b6d655f72696768745f677265656e5f3030373230302e706e67"
    alt="Fork me on GitHub" data-canonical-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_right_green_007200.png"></a>

</body>

</html>
```

Concentrate on this part of the code:

```
$('.click-splitflap')
.splitFlap({
    textInit: 'Click me ',
    autoplay: false,
    onComplete: function() {
        console.log('Done !');
    }
})
.click(function() {
    $(this).splitFlap('splitflap').animate();
});
```

I need to switch `.click` to `.delay`, but if I do and give the appropriate `ms`, the whole plug-in wouldn't work. Could anyone shine some light on this?

Comment: Please, provide a demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading what's documented at the [**plugin**](https://github.com/zemax/jquery-splitFlap), I would think it's quite straightforward. Using `delay` on an object will only work for some special synchronous methods by default but any functions can be adapted to show this behaviour by using `.queue()`. Most logical to me would seem to be this then :

```
$('.click-splitflap')
.splitFlap({autoplay: false}) // prevents automatic animation
.delay(2000).queue(function() {

    $(this).dequeue().splitFlap('splitflap').animate(); // starts the animation
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Here's the smallest of demos to show the basic functionality :

[**Link**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYZQVZ?editors=001)

Answer (score 1):

So, after reading the documentation, it states that the plugin needs a chars.png image that has the character map on it. You have to host this chars.png on your server and link to in the splitflap constructor with the value idendifier "image".

Then you can call a set timeout function to animate.

HTML

```
<div class="example">
    <h1>Simple Split-Flap</h1>
    <div class="delay-splitflap">It worked</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: grey;
    color: white;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.example {
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
h1 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #333333;
}
.splitflap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: top center;
    -moz-perspective-origin: top center;
    -ms-perspective-origin: top center;
    perspective-origin: top center;
    -webkit-perspective: 900px;
    -moz-perspective: 900px;
    -ms-perspective: 900px;
    perspective: 900px;
}
```

JS/ Jquery/ Splitflap

```
// You need the chars.png link to make it work.
// Download this image and host it on ur server.
// Then link the location in the splitFlap
// Object constructor like i did below.
var chars = 'http://lab.les-mains-dans-le-code.fr/splitflap/images/chars.png';

$(document).ready(function(){

  // set constructor values
  $('.delay-splitflap').splitFlap({
      image: chars,
      textInit:   'waiting 4',
      autoplay:   false,
      onComplete: function () {
          console.log('Done !');
      }
  })

  // Use set timeout to wait 4 sec.
  setTimeout(function(){
      $('.delay-splitflap').splitFlap('splitflap').animate();
  },4000);

});
```

Hope this helps.

[WORKING JS FIDDLE OF ANIMATION](http://jsfiddle.net/00d85u4k/)